# Какие есть аналоги CodePush?

Tags: react-native

Проект на ReactNative ищу библиотеку для обновления JS кода без участия магазина, что есть кроме CodePush?

Comment: https://rollout.io/

Answer (score 0):

Могу порекомендовать http://expo.io.

В последних версиях sdk добавили поддержку каналов публикации приложения, позволяет удобно разделить продакшн и дев/стейдж версии приложение и обновлять без заливки приложения в магазины.

Активно развивают связку с CI, если немного постараться можно настроить ;).

Из минусов нет возможности установить и использовать нативные модули, хотя обычно хватает встроенных.